# Substring method to return start to string.length() if the end index is out of bounds?

Tags: java, string, substring, indexoutofboundsexception

Basically the title.

```
String text = "abcdef";
String pattern = "defg";
int start = 3;
int end = 3 + pattern.length();
System.out.println(text.substring(start,end));
```

Now that throws index out of bounds error but is there some API that can work around this.
Right now I'm just doing

```
if (end > text.length()){
end = text.length();
}
```

Comment: I think what you're doing is basically the only way.  Slightly shorter: `text.substring(start, end > text.length() ? text.length() : end)`

Answer (score 0):

Similar approach but with Math.min to tackle it in a shorter way:

```
text.substring(start, Math.min(end, text.length()));
```